# Answered tab in the home page of Ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Can we have a tab labeled "Accepted", like "Active", which will show recently accepted answers (including all at the end).

I am asking this because in heavy moderation time, there are questions coming one by one very quickly, which can confuse a new Ask Ubuntu user. I also suggesting that tab to be default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get enough reputation (10k to be more precise) you get access to a lot more information than probably you want.

The [`access to moderator tools`](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege will allow you to check most of everything the site has.

A preview of most of the tools available when you reach the 10k reputation mark is [displayed here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2290/how-does-the-site-look-like-to-a-moderator). They are not the same but there are a lot of common functions.

Until then you can simply search the site with a lot of possible filters, a cool one that might help you sort out recent questions with accepted answers is `hasaccepted:1`, try that in the search box from the main site and it will return all the questions in Ask Ubuntu that have accepted answers.

Sort that by activity or by creation and you have something close to what you request, [***have a look here!***](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3a1)

I can sort of understand some usefulness to your request, but because of the already implemented solutions and tools and style I don't really agree that we need to clutter the main site with another tab.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the point of this, most users who land on the site don't land here because they know to go to http://askubuntu.com - they come from a search result on a search engine. The stream shows recently modified/new questions, regardless of if they're accepted or not. As most users who are staring at the homepage are experienced users, making a list of all the accepted questions helps a very small population of the site on the home page.

If you're interested in questions that have answers, you can use [the search functions](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3a1) to weed out only those with answers.

Comment: I was talking about askubuntu.com main site! anyway got the point

Comment: I was also talking about the main site