# Can we have "tools" link at the top of Ask Ubuntu site?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, 10k-tools

For users (not moderators) who have more than 10,000 reputation and who have access to o moderator tools why doesn't exist a link for [tools](https://askubuntu.com/tools) at the top of Ask Ubuntu site?

How can we have it there? I found [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2292/147044) that the moderators have it.

Comment: What's wrong with the usual way for non-moderators to access the 10k tools? (Click *review*, then click *tools* on the left.)

Comment: @EliahKagan There is nothing wrong, but wouldn't be simpler just one click instead of two (this is what I think, sorry if I'm wrong)?

Comment: I agree, actually. I was just wondering if there was a problem; I agree that it would be best for a *tools* link to be added, though it's not a high-priority feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand why regular users are denied to have a link for tools there, since the link can be accessed anyway at http://www.askubuntu.com/tools.

But, I just made the following userscript that can be helpful in this sense:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Tools link for Ask Ubuntu
// @version    0.1
// @match      http://askubuntu.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

// --- add "tools" link in front of "review" link    
var reviewLink      = document.querySelector ("a[href='/review']");
var toolsLink       = document.createElement ();
toolsLink.innerHTML = '<a href="/tools">tools</a>&nbsp;<span class="lsep">|</span>&nbsp;';

reviewLink.parentNode.insertBefore(toolsLink, reviewLink);
```

Also, this userscript can be found at:

- https://github.com/radu-radeanu/userscripts/raw/master/au_style.user.js

The script need to be installed in the browser as follow:

- Chromium / Chrome users need [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo/related?hl=en).
- Firefox users need [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).

More about: http://userscripts.org/about/installing.

It will look something like this:

[image: tools]

Answer (score 8):

The **/tools** link was removed some time ago (that screenshot is from Jan '12) , and **/review** is there in its place.

The whole point of the feature is to make it easier for mods/editors to find stuff that might be worth checking out, and **/review** is more efficient at that, so it gets a prime spot at the top.