# Can ♦ moderators see our real name or e-mail?

Tags: discussion

Just as the question stated. I know it is marked under the private section of our profile, but I was just wondering if you could see stuff like that. And if you don't, do you see anything else that a normal/regular user wouldn't see?

Comment: Same answer != duplicate. I don't even think that other post answer the question anyway. Reopening.

Comment: real name != name you provide :-)

Comment: One other point worth making is that a lot of people who "moderate" (eg edit, review, nominate to close/reopen, etc) aren't actual "moderators" but regular users with a high enough reputation level.  These people can *not* see private information in profiles.  I just wanted to make the distinction, because you may think of all these people as if they are "moderators" when only those with the ♦ next to their names are official moderators.

Comment: @neon_overload I edited the title.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, moderators can see your real name and email, although this information isn't something we see on your profile by default, we have to click several buttons to see it. We also have to agree to abide by the [Stack Exchange Moderator Agreement](https://askubuntu.com/legal/moderator-agreement) when we become moderators. This states:

> ii. I acknowledge that I may have access to potentially
>   personally-identifying information about Ask Ubuntu users and that in
>   connection with such access
>
> a. I will use such information solely in accordance with the then-current Privacy Policy of Ask Ubuntu,
>
> b. I will not disclose this information to anyone,
>
> c. I will not store or copy this information and
>
> d. I will only use such information in connection with performance as a Ask Ubuntu moderator for the benefit of Ask Ubuntu.

So you can be sure that your information is pretty safe.

As to your question about other things we can see, moderators have access to [all privileges](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) as well as [various other tools](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2290/how-does-the-site-look-like-to-a-moderator) used in the moderation of the site. If you have any more specific questions ask away.

Comment: Additionally, the viewing of personal data is itself logged to the system. This provides some level of deterrent against abuse.

Comment: This is the reason I don't fill out these fields and use a bogus email.

Comment: @don.joey that is the reason why the do not necessarily have your *real* name ;)

Comment: Byt why the labeled as "Private"??? then according to your answer they are not private OR perhaps I don't know real mean of the "Private". why??? or it will better if re-label to "share with Moderator". I really unlike this >:o, why site didn't tell that the moderator can see my Private Email ??? Also in Email text box titled "never displayed,..". at least you could replace it "show only for moderator..."

Comment: @KasiyA Private means private to only special people or not visible to all public. And this is the normal meaning of private in **all** sites. If no one can see it then it isn't useful.

Comment: @PhoneixS :D :D Then public means public to all private or not visible to only special people, right?? :D . **MAN** this is not my answer and I'm not at all happy about this.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are upset about @KasiyA, do you think we are going to spam your email or something?

Comment: I'm not upset, I I just furious, but not about you and other moderators, about the "Private" label. they could labeled it as not private then I was not upset about that, so it's labeled "Private" while @PhoneixS [in his comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12006/can-%E2%99%A6-moderators-see-our-real-name-or-e-mail#comment21031_12007) says me "it means private to only special people". Then why the SITE not told me it means "private to only special people" if that is true. sorry for down vote,sorry

Comment: @KasiyA to tell you an example, when you fill a bank form they said that the information is private but they can access it and many of them have a closure of what they can do or not with the data that you must accept. This is why when working with services you normally sign an agreement of privacy. In askubuntu you have "By registering, you agree to the [privacy policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) and [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service)." when registering.