# What does the site look like to a moderator? (2.0)

Tags: discussion, moderation

*[What does the site look like to a moderator?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2290/what-does-the-site-look-like-to-a-moderator)*

Has anything changed from 12 years ago?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote my last answer, *it's not drastically different*. 95%+ of moderator time is the the same old flag queue though.

But the tools accessible through the admin section are slightly better laid out (see below) so we can find niche tools a bit easier. We also have a little more access to see what's going on than we did before. They're pretty slight changes.

[image: Admin links]